# nginx is now 404 Not Found

Tags: apt, server, nginx, vps, composer

I had nginx before, but now it's 404 on web. Maybe something restarting, but I don't know for sure.

```
404 Not Found
nginx/1.18.0 (Ubuntu)
```

I have searched for various errors nginx. sudo nginx -t is ok.

/var/log/nginx/error.log

```
[notice] 60852#60852: signal process started
```

curl -I https://test.com

```
HTTP1.1 404 Not Found
Server: nginx/1.18.0 (Ununtu)
Date: Thu, 27 Aug 21:02:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 162
Connection: keep-alive
```

/etc/nginx/sites-available/test.conf

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
root /var/www/html/test.com/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name test.com www.test.com;

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.4-fpm.sock;
}

include /var/www/html/test.com/.nginx.conf;

# new lines
listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
listen 443 ssl; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/test.com/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}
```

/etc/nginx/nginx.conf

```
user www-data;
worker_processes auto;
pid /run/nginx.pid;
include /etc/nginx/modules-enabled/*.conf;

events {
    worker_connections 768;
}

http {

    sendfile on;
    tcp_nopush on;
    tcp_nodelay on;
    keepalive_timeout 65;
    types_hash_max_size 2048;

    include /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type application/octet-stream;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3; # Dropping SSLv3, ref: POODLE
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;

    access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
    error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

    gzip on;


    include /etc/nginx/conf.d/*.conf;
    include /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/*;
}
```

sudo service nginx reload, ok

Can you help me?

Comment: The 404 means that nginx is running, so you still have it. It can't find your web site, though (I don't know why, that's why I'm posting this as a comment.)

Comment: Yes sure. So nginx in general it works (ok / successful / security), But this website it still works not. Can you please works again?

Comment: Is www-data:www-data the owner?

Comment: /var/www/html/test.com, is www-data:www-data (chown/chgrp) and 755 (chmod)

Answer (score 0):

"`404 Not Found`" means that the system can't find a particular resource on a web server. So the issue is with the server. So, try again tomorrow.

Comment: I already have HTTPS. So nginx in general it works (ok / successful / security), But this website it still works not.

Answer (score 0):

Some Ngnix-based virtual servers need exact IP addresses.
It's to easy check by this:

```
curl http://myvirtualdomain.com 
  <-- return 404 error
curl -vk https://myvirtualdomain.com 
  <-- OK
```

This is caused by `nginx` configurations.

Add your server's IP address on your virtual server block:

```
server {
listen 80;
listen [::]:80;
root /var/www/html/test.com/public;
index index.php index.html index.htm;
server_name test.com www.test.com;

listen 10x.32.22.xx;   # adds your server ip
```

That's a key point of my `nginx` server configurations.